# Query Unity for all instance of an Interface

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, inversion-of-control, unity-container

I need to find out in my project, all the classes that implement an interface called IMyInterface and are registered with the Unity Container.

Anyone know of a way to do this, without having unity create the instance of the Objects which are registered with Unity?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can query the registrations in a container instance using a query like this

```
var x = container.Registrations.Where(cm => cm.RegisteredType == typeof(IMyInterface));
```

Comment: @user457485 If my answer solved your problem it would be great if you could mark it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can first query for all the types that are not abstract and implement your interface:

```
this.GetType().Assembly.GetTypes().Where(type => type.IsClass &&
                                              !type.IsAbstract &&
                                              type.IsAssignableFrom(IMyInterface));
```

Then for each of those types, query your Unity container to see if it contains an instance of it.